# Spark-SQL 3.x insert date column as 1970-01-01 by default

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While using Spark 3.x thrift server, I found its inserting date columns as '1970-01-01'. I tried to to cast the value as date but same result.

Steps to reproduce:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example(HistoryDate DATE)`

`insert into example values(cast('2018-01-01' as date))`

But it save the date column as '1970-01-01' as default. Any body knows why this is happending?

I just check timestamp is working fine and insert the actual data.

Comment: Just store this as string and handle this in your database level

Comment: Is it a wrok around? Why we should us String if we already have Date type in Spark-SQL?